# Is there a way to tell what direction the state is going with history.js?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, browser-history, html5-history, history.js

Like the title says, I'd like to be able to perform a different `onstatechange` event if the `pushState` function is called, instead of the `back` function. Or, if the `go` function is negative or positive.

Example:

if `History.pushState()` or `History.go(1)` are called, I want the `statechange` event's callback to be `forwardPushState`

if `History.back()` or `History.go(-1)` are called, I want the `statechange` event's callback to be `backwardsPushState`

Comment: Keep track of the last visited page, if the current page redirects to the last visited page, chances are the direction is backwards.

Comment: It will be better if you illustrate by an example. regards

Comment: PushState pushes a new state in the stack (a state is some data stored after a new action). It has no relationship with back and go. Back and go are functions to navigate over pushed states in stack. I say this because in your edit, it looks like you are thinking that pushState and go(1) are equivalent.

Comment: I know they aren't the same, just giving an example of what i was looking for

Comment: @adeneo, could you please explain more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751263/how-to-catch-a-state-change-event-once-with-history-js

Comment: Please to follow this topic maybe it will be useful for you. There is an answer there about how to track the onstatechange event and ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692314/history-api-html5-how-to-know-when-user-clicked-in-next-back-browser-buttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A state is some data related to a page (as the user see it in the browser). If the user wants to be in a certain page, this page is the same, either he is coming from back button click or from forward button click.

PushState pushes a new state in the stack. It has no relationship with `back` and `go`. `Back` and `go` are functions to navigate over pushed states in stack. I say this because in your edit, it looks like you are thinking that pushState and go(1) are equivalent.

Maybe if you want to know from which direction the user is coming, you should analyse `onstatechange` event to know if it takes any parameter that stores direction, which is not a trivial task IMO.

The main thing I think, is that it has no relationship with the go `(-1)` or `go(1)` or `back`.

Comment: i do realize that `pushState` and `go(1)` arent the same, its just an example. Unfortunately there really is no relationship, or link to do what im looking for, so i have to do something like what @adeneo said

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
<html>
<body onunload="disableBackButton()">
<h1>You should not come back to this page</h1>
</body>
<script>
function disableBackButton()
{
   window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
</script>
</html>
```

The code above will make it difficult to use the back button to load this page.

Second try

The code below was taken from another stack overflow.

[detect back button click in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser)

```
window.onload = function () {
if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
    history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
        // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
        // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
    };
}
else {
    var ignoreHashChange = true;
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        if (!ignoreHashChange) {
            ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.location.hash = Math.random();
            // Detect and redirect change here
            // Works in older FF and IE9
            // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
            // delimiter on the end of the URL
        }
        else {
            ignoreHashChange = false;   
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Not trying to disable the backbutton